# Open Source Database Plugin For Eclipse?

Tags: database, eclipse, ide

Does anyone know of a good open source plugin for database querying and exploring within Eclipse?

The active Database Exploring plugin within Eclipse is really geared around being associated with a Java project. While I am just trying to run ad-hoc queries and explore the schema. I am effectively looking for a just a common, quick querying tool without the overhead of having to create a code project. I have found a couple open source database plugins for Eclipse but these have not seen active development in over a year.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use SQL Explorer.

It comes as an Eclipse plugin or standalone.

http://eclipsesql.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

I use Quantum DB, and it seems to work quite well.

http://quantum.sourceforge.net/

Comment: This does not have command completion.